# Nginx redirecting to http from https

Tags: nginx, safari, redirect

I have configured nginx to serve static content only some path (`/url_path`).

Following is path of my nginx config:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = "http" ) {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
    }

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 5;

    root /absolute/local/path;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/app-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app-error.log;

    rewrite_log on;

    location /url_path {
        alias   /absolute/local/path;
    }
    ...
}
```

My nginx server is behind `awselb2.0` which is configured to forward requests received on `https` port to `http` port on our machines running nginx server on `http`.

Request follows below pattern:

```
BROWSER --HTTPS--> ELB --HTTP--> NGINX
BROWSER <--HTTPS-- ELB <--HTTP-- NGINX
```

When request request through curl, it show double redirect for some request, that should have been served without any redirect.

```
$ curl -L https://example.com/url_path

HTTP/2 301
location: http://example.com/url_path                                    # Recieved first redirect
server: nginx/1.12.2
cache-control: public

> curl another request to this URL: 'http://example.com/url_path'        # Followed first redirect

< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Wed, 13 Mar 2019 06:45:16 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Server: nginx/1.12.2
< Location: https://example.com/url_path                                 # Recieved second redirect

> curl another request to this URL: 'https://example.com/url_path'       # Followed second redirect

< HTTP/2 200                                                            # Request was served this time.
< date: Wed, 13 Mar 2019 06:45:17 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 1158
< server: nginx/1.12.2
< last-modified: Tue, 12 Mar 2019 18:42:03 GMT
< etag: "5c87fd7b-486"
< cache-control: public
< accept-ranges: bytes
```

I am not able to understand, why would nginx redirect from https to http. Problem seems to be with `alias` only in nginx config, since when I use `proxy_pass` with node server (express) running, there is no redirect.

Even with this behaviour, chrome and firefox work fine, but this doesn't seems to be the case with safari as it throws CORS error(sometimes).

There is one more thing that in last request from curl, it was following:

```
* Found bundle for host example.com: 0x7f9d2ac24a50 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host example.com
```

Not sure it's helpful, but this is using the first connect it created when it request `https` resource.